# wamp html script not updating

Tags: php, html, localhost, wamp

I am trying to run a php based web app locally using wamp. On making changes to the html script in .php file, the page does not get updated. However, changes in css files are being updated. Any fixes to the issue?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the issue. What have you tried? Have you tried deleting the contents of the entire file just to see if anything is running or using an error_log or var_dump? Maybe the code you are updating is in a conditional that isn't being fulfilled. Are you using a framework or cms that is employing some sort of caching?

Comment: Very less information

Comment: @CodeWizard: On deleting, it is not displaying the contents on the page.

Comment: On restoring the contents, it has started displaying the changes. But still unable to trace what caused the problem.

Comment: Show us the script .. and which part doesn't get updated .. we cant guess the problem

Comment: Based on the fact that the contents aren't being displayed we can assume there isn't an error as it sounds like they were displaying before. Further we can assume there is a conditional that isn't being met further up your code. Use you var dump and error log to debug. Or post the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your code changes dont get reflected when you view the page, it has probably been cached by the browser.

Always use CTRL + F5 so the cache is refreshed when making changes.

Alternatively most browsers have developer extension and one of those is usually an option to turn off caching. You should look for that and set it while developing a site.

[How do I Disable FireFox's Browser Cache COMPLETELY?](http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2011/05/19/145440.aspx)

[How to disable caching in Internet Explorer 9?](https://superuser.com/questions/461285/how-to-disable-caching-in-internet-explorer-9)

[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Answer (score 3):

If you disable both of these lines in the php.ini file, this should no longer happen.

soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0

opcache.enable=0

At least that worked for me.

Hope it helps.